# Visual studio Run time error for windows server 2008 R2 64bit

Tags: visual-c++, runtime-error, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run my 32 bit application on windows server 2008 R2 64bit, but it is crashing giving visual studio runtime error.

I installed visual studio 2008 redistributable. But still I am getting the same error. Any idea how to fix this, or what else is needed in windows 2008 server R2. The application is working fine in windows 7 os 64bit or 32 bit. But failing in server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- Ensure you are running Release build and not Debug build
- Ensure correct VC++ redist is installed. Redist must match the platform (64-bit or 32-bit), the version and the service pack.
- Check that any dependent DLLs is not missing. You may use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) on target machine.

Dependency Walker may also help in other errors (not just DLL missing).

Also, you must ideally put more details (preferbly a screenshot and error/exception code) on why your program is crashing.